# Group by summarize in between dates with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I'm struggling to understand some of the logic in dplyr when using summarize.

I'm interested in calculating some statistic of interest (for example, a mean of some column) for each date within each ID and I have data that includes a start_date and end_date column.

Let's say I have hierarchical data with an `IDsub` column for each row, an `ID` column for each broader category that IDsub falls into, a `start_date`, an `end_date`, and a meaningful `value`:

```
IDsub <- c("1001", "1002", "1003", "1004")
ID <- c("id1", "id1", "id2", "id2")
start_date <- as.Date(c("2021-01-01", "2021-01-02", "2021-01-05", "2021-01-10"))
end_date <- as.Date(c("2021-01-10", "2021-01-09", "2021-01-13", "2021-01-12"))
value <- c(1, 2, 2, 0)

df <- tibble(IDsub, ID, start_date, end_date, value)
```

The original data look like this:

```
IDsub ID    start_date end_date   value
1001  id1   2021-01-01 2021-01-10     1
1002  id1   2021-01-02 2021-01-09     2
1003  id2   2021-01-05 2021-01-13     2
1004  id2   2021-01-10 2021-01-12     0
```

I then transform the data so that it's organized by `date`:

```
df1 <- df %>%
  transmute(ID, IDsub, value, date = map2(min(df$start_date), max(df$end_date), seq, by = "day")) %>%
  unnest("date")
```

Which results in the following:

```
ID    IDsub value   date      
id1   1001      1 2021-01-01
id1   1001      1 2021-01-02
id1   1001      1 2021-01-03
id1   1001      1 2021-01-04
...
id2   1004      0 2021-01-10
id2   1004      0 2021-01-11
id2   1004      0 2021-01-12
id2   1004      0 2021-01-13
```

Here is where I get tripped up. I want to calculate the mean of `value` for each `date` within each `ID`, but the following code doesn't appear to do that.

```
df2 <- df1 %>%
  group_by(ID, date) %>%
  summarize(mean(value))
```

The previous code produces the following output:

```
ID    date       `mean(value)`
id1   2021-01-01           1.5
id1   2021-01-02           1.5
id1   2021-01-03           1.5
id1   2021-01-04           1.5
id1   2021-01-05           1.5
```

This doesn't make sense, since 2020-01-01 for id1 should have a different mean value than 2020-01-02 for id1, because only IDsub 1001 with value=1 waspresent on 2021-01-01, while IDsub 1001 and 1002 with values of 1 and 2, respectively, were both present on 2021-01-02. So the values for 2021-01-01 and 2021-01-02 should be different but they're not.

I'm clearly missing something simple here.

Comment: What should be the value for 2020-01-01 for id1 & 2020-01-02 for id1? `df1 %>%
  filter(between(date, as.Date('2021-01-01'), as.Date('2021-01-02'))) %>%
  filter(ID == "id1") %>% 
  arrange(date)`

Comment: For 2021-01-01 and id1, the mean should be 1. For 2021-01-02 and id1, the mean should be 1.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your map2 statement is incorrect.
Here is another possible option using lubridate's `within` function.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df <- structure(list(IDsub = c("1001", "1002", "1003", "1004"), 
                     ID = c("id1", "id1", "id2", "id2"), 
                     start_date = structure(c(18628, 18629, 18632, 18637), class = "Date"), 
                     end_date = structure(c(18637, 18636, 18640, 18639), class = "Date"), 
                     value = c(1, 2, 2, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

#find start end date and create sequence
firstdate <- min(df$start_date)
lastdate <- max(df$end_date)
timeseq <-seq(firstdate, lastdate, by="1 day")

#split by id
dflist<-split(df, df$ID)
lapply(names(dflist), function(dfname){
   
   iddf<-dflist[[dfname]]
   #create time intervals for each row 
   intervals <-interval(iddf$start_date, iddf$end_date)
   meanvalues <- sapply(timeseq, function(nrow){
      withinresult <- nrow %within% intervals
      mean(iddf$value[withinresult], na.rm=TRUE)
   })
   tibble(dfname, timeseq, meanvalues)
})
```

The final result from the `lapply` statement is a list of data frames by ID.  One could bind these together and reshape depending on the final intent.

Comment: Thanks, this looks promising. Do you have any idea how to group by ID here so meanvalues are reported by date within ID (by date for id1 separately from id2)?